# Centering 'Page' word over page numbers in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, alignment

I want to make the word 'Page' centered over page numbers for the following [Latex template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/just-thesis-template/mvrtfbhpfgbd) in the following pages:

- table of contents
- table of figures
- table of tables

I tried this [solution](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21480), but it's not reliable since I have 'Title/Table/Figure' words on the other side of the page.

The following is a screenshot of the current template ('page' word aligned right):
[image]

Comment: I am not sure, where the word "Page" should apear, do you want to write it as table heading or do you want to write it above the pagenumber of the page, where the toc/tof/tot is printed to?

Comment: @Ahrtaler I've updated the question to be more clear

Comment: I think, I know what you mean. The problem is, that the pagenumbers are aligned right. That means, if you want, that "Page" is centered above the pagenumbers, also the pagenumbers have to be aligned centered. I am not sure, how to align them centered. Setting the alignment of "Page" centered, means, to override the `\tableofcontents` command of the class. Setting the alignment of "Page" wouldn't effect anything, if you keep this implementation. But I am sorry. My LaTeX skills are not good enougth to set the alignment of toc-pagenumbers and "Page".

Comment: @Ahrtaler yes that's what I want, thank you anyway,waiting for an answer from latex expert, I think it's not easy

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by *centered*? In your example should Page be centered with respect to the page I, or the page II, or in the middle of II?

Here is some code for you, and others, to try.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{Title \protect\hfill \rlap{\hspace{-1.5em}Page}

\chapter{Dedication}
\lipsum
\chapter{Acknowledgement}
\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\end{document}
```

The `\addtocontents{file}{text}` inserts `text` into `file` where `file` is normally one of `toc`, `lof` or `lot` for the table of contents and the list of... files.

The `\rlap` effectively makes its argument take zero space and then the `\hspace{-1.5em} moves the zero-spaced text left the given amount. This should be adjusted to your particular document design.

I found one problem with the above code in that an error (`missing \item ?`) was reported for the Dedication ToC entry. Just ignoring this everything looked well. Hopefully somebody will provide a solution to this.

I have now found a solution as below:

```
% tocpageprob.tex SE 505981
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}
%\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{Title \protect\hfill \rlap{\hspace{-1.5em}Page}\par}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Dedication}
\lipsum
\chapter{Acknowledgement}
\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\end{document}
```

I messed up my original code for the `\addtocontents{toc}{...}`